# Group multiple td in parent element for child component

Tags: vue.js

I have a layout similar to this:

My parent component is this:

```
<!-- Parent -->
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Some</th>
            <th>Column</th>
            <th>Names</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr v-for="thing in things">
            <td>{{ thing.id }}</td>
            <my-child-component :thing="thing"></my-child-component>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And my child component is like this:

```
<!-- Child Component -->
<template>
    <td>{{ thing.foo }}</td>
    <td>{{ thing.bar }}</td>
    <td>{{ thing.baz }}</td>
</template>
```

I know you're required to have a single top level element in Vue (2.0), but I wondered if there's an "invisible" element that I can use. I know you can use `v-for` in  a `<template>` tag but that won't work in my case.

Or, is there some wrapper that isn't going to break everything. I tried div/span etc but it was horrible and non-semantic.

Basically what I want is for the table header columns to line up with the tbody contents (I have been down the road of having a td with colspan set on it and putting a table inside that, but the columns don't always line up.

PS The real thing is much more complex than the example above, and I am presenting tabular data so don't want to hack about with css to reproduce a table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you say that "the real thing is more complex", it's hard to tell if this will work in your case, but one way to do it could be something like this:

```
<tbody>
    <my-child-component :things="things"></my-child-component>
</tbody>
```

And then in the child component:

```
<tr v-for="thing in things">
    <td>{{ thing.id }}</td>
    <td>{{ thing.foo }}</td>
    <td>{{ thing.bar }}</td>
    <td>{{ thing.baz }}</td>
</tr>
```

Not sure if this would work in your scenario?

Comment: I had totally forgotten I asked this question! I'm guilty of leaving unanswered questions. But yes, that would work, as would `<my-component v-for="thing in things" :key="thing.id"></my-component>` with a `tr` as the child.

Comment: No worries, I had totally missed that I had the wrong filters applied, so I actually thought it was a new question :)